# Why is the django logging-config not being applied to all logger-instances?

Tags: python, django, logging, uvicorn

Python 3.8, Django 3.0

I use `docker-compose logs` to display and process the logs of a container with django. To ensure that all of the output has the same format, I  define `LOGGING` inside of `settings.py`

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'detailed': {
            'format': '{levelname} [{asctime}]{name} :  {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'level': env('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL'),
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'detailed'
            },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': env('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL'),
        },
        # django.template and django.backends must not use DEBUG-level, since it is buggy
        'django.template': {
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        # use same format for logs from uvicorn
        'uvicorn': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    }
}
```

However, when running the container I get the following output in the logs:

```sh
django_1    | INFO [2020-04-28 16:00:25,482]uvicorn.error :  Started server process [16]
django_1    | INFO [2020-04-28 16:00:25,482]uvicorn.error :  Waiting for application startup.
django_1    | INFO [2020-04-28 16:00:25,482]uvicorn.error :  ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported.
django_1    | INFO [2020-04-28 16:00:25,482]uvicorn.error :  Application startup complete.
django_1    | WARNING:  Detected file change in 'myproject/settings.py'. Reloading...
django_1    | INFO [2020-04-28 16:04:01,080]uvicorn.error :  Shutting down
django_1    | INFO [2020-04-28 16:04:01,180]uvicorn.error :  Finished server process [16]
django_1    | INFO [2020-04-28 16:04:01,888]uvicorn.error :  Started server process [18]
django_1    | INFO [2020-04-28 16:04:01,888]uvicorn.error :  Waiting for application startup.
django_1    | INFO [2020-04-28 16:04:01,888]uvicorn.error :  ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported.
django_1    | INFO [2020-04-28 16:04:01,888]uvicorn.error :  Application startup complete.
```

As you can see, uvicorn uses the logging.config I specified. However, this one call `WARNING:  Detected file change in 'myproject/settings.py'. Reloading...` does not follow the pattern. This is very weird, because the message gets called inside `lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/supervisors/statreload.py` with

```py
logger = logging.getLogger("uvicorn.error")
# ...
# ...
# ...
display_path = os.path.normpath(filename)
if Path.cwd() in Path(filename).parents:
   display_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.relpath(filename))
message = "Detected file change in '%s'. Reloading..."
logger.warning(message, display_path)
```

At least that's where I think this warning is coming from. So why doesn't my config apply to this?

While trying to locate the origin of the problem I've discovered one more curious thing:

When I call a logger directly inside `settings.py` it also does not apply the configuration:

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("django")
logger.warning("hello")
```

will just display

```sh
WARNING:  hello
```

But when I use the same code in a view `myapp/views.py` I get

```sh
django_1    | INFO [2020-04-28 16:14:07,960]uvicorn.error :  Application startup complete.
django_1    | WARNING [2020-04-28 16:14:12,789]django :  hello
django_1    | INFO [2020-04-28 16:14:12,942]uvicorn.access :  172.20.0.5:43470 - "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200
```

So as it seems the root of the problem is maybe not uvicorn, but that the logging config only applies to some specific modules?

What exactly is wrong here? Why is this behaving so strangely? Or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: The "realoading" message is from "uvicorn.error" logger, try setup such logger in django logging config.

Comment: Already tried that. As you can see in the snippets of my output it actually logs stuff from `uvicorn.error`. Just not this particular message.

Comment: The uvicorn supvervisor process is not the one running django, so you are not overwriting its logging config. see `unicorn/basereload.py`. Try setup uvicorn logging alone. see https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/